# Related product makes product created_at messed up

Tags: magento

Following this thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/why-is-created-at-customer-entity-table-set-to-change-on-update, I notice the same issue also occurs in catalog_product_entity table.

Using Magento CE 1.8.1.0, every time I save after adding Related Products or Up-Sell Products, the created_at timestamp got changed by a random date.

Is this also another Magento bug?